# Open one/multiple directories and select items in Windows 10 using C++

Tags: c++, directory, windows-10, shellexecute

I know there are already some questions regarding this topic, but none of them seem to be working under Windows 10.

I am trying to feed some function a path to a file/folder, which then opens this file/folder in an explorer (or better the default software regarding opening directories). If possible it then should also preselect those files.

As a reference point we could use the default argv[0] syntax.

Things i tried before:

```
void BrowseToFile(LPCTSTR filename)
{
    
   // ITEMIDLIST* pidl = ILCreateFromPath(filename);
    ITEMIDLIST* pidl = ILCreateFromPathW(filename);
    
    if (pidl) {
        SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidl, 0, 0, 0);
        ILFree(pidl);
    }
}
```

This does compile but just does nothing when i feed any sort of path that is LPCTSTR conform.

I also tried

```
#include <shellapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "shell32")

    ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", LPCWSTR(filesystem::path(std::filesystem::directory_entry(argv[0])).c_str()), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
```

, which also does compile and doesn't prone any errors but no matter what sort of path i feed it, even when I manually feed it LPCWSTR("C:\") as the path, it just doesn't do anything.

The solution that sounds the most suited would probably be an implementation of the SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems function (shlobj_core.h).

But after searching through 4 result sites of google searches, no syntax leads to a working prototype.

Maybe someone could share a solution that fits modern style C++, atleast on Windows 10 which is my targeted platform rn.
I am ofc using C++20.

**EDIT**

My current Code looks like

```
void BrowseToFile(LPCTSTR filename)
{

    ITEMIDLIST* pidl = ILCreateFromPathW(filename);
    if (pidl) {
        CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
        SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidl, 0, 0, 0);
        ILFree(pidl);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    BrowseToFile(LPCTSTR(argv[0]));
}
```

and it still doesn't work..

Comment: Pay attention to the Remarks section in the documentation of the [SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shopenfolderandselectitems#remarks) function. Quote: "_[`CoInitialize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/objbase/nf-objbase-coinitialize) or [`CoInitializeEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializeex) must be called before using `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems`. Not doing so causes `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems` to fail._"

Comment: can you take a look at the added code in the question and point me towards my misstake on why it still does nothing?

Comment: Add logging: output the argv[0], output the HRESULT from the call.

Comment: I suppose you are compiling with `UNICODE` enabled (because nowadays this is the only viable option). So, when `UNICODE` is defined, `LPCTSTR` is defined as `LPCWSTR`, which expands to `const wchar_t*`, which means a pointer to a wide-character string (null-terminated, C-style). This means your `BrowseToFile` function expects a `const wchar_t*` parameter (so far, so good). You are calling the wide (`W`) version of `ILCreateFromPath` on the filename (`ILCreateFromPathW`, also correct). However, `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` does not provide you with wide (`wchar_t*`) arguments, so (1/2)…

Comment: … (2/2) for the `wchar_t*` version, you'll need [`in wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/using-wmain?view=msvc-170) instead. The way you are doing it currently: `BrowseToFile(LPCTSTR(argv[0]));` you just order the compiler to shut up by using a god-cast `LPCTSTR(…)` without understanding Unicode/ANSI differences. Don't do it, don't cast incompatible types (`char*` vs `wchar_t*`). Another error is that you use `argv[0]`, which is **not** the first argument passed via command line: it is the name of the executable itself. Use `argv[1]` instead.

Comment: this totally makes sense! I will try that! :) im using argv[0] just as a reference to a right formatted path that definetly exists ^^

Comment: And, of course (as already mentioned by Dave), check return codes of each function you call: what does `CoInitializeEx` return, is it `S_OK`? What does `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems` return, is it `S_OK`? Make error handling a habit. Especially before asking further questions. Also, remember that when passing a string by hand, you need to escape backslashes, and that wide strings require an L-prefix, for example: `L"C:\\"` to open the root folder of the C-drive.

Comment: You sir, are a god :D it works!!! thx a bunch <3 cant do more than like the comment and thank you sadly..

Comment: @Gisbert12843 note that `LPCWSTR(filesystem::path(std::filesystem::directory_entry(argv[0])).c_str()` can be simplified to `filesystem::path(argv[0]).c_str()`. Also, don't call `CoInitializeEx()` in `BrowseToFile()`, it belongs in `(w)main()` instead.

Comment: Hey you here too! :D I switched it around a bit.. it wasn't needed to switch to wmain for my purposes here ^^ once im done with the project i will post my solution as an answer for other people!

Ofc I shortened those casts to a minimum by now :D i wasnt sure at the time how to shortcut some of these conversions ngl

But its good to know that CoInitializeEx() works like the initiliazer for random numbers in c++ ^^ I will adjust to that! thx :)